# How can I write an if then statement using "this" to determine if a field is empty?

Tags: jquery

I am simply trying to toggleClass on something based on if the form element is focused and if it's empty or not.  But I can't figure out how to write the if then statement to test whether the field is empty or not.

Here is what I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.step').focus(function() {

   $(this).next("div").toggleClass("selected").fadeTo(500, 1);

  });

  $('.step').blur(function() {

   if($(this[value==""])){
    $(this).next("div").toggleClass("selected").fadeTo(250, 0.5);
   }else{
    return;
   }
  });
 });
```

I have tried also `if($(this).is(":empty"){` and it just kept acting like the field was empty even if it wasn't.

I also tried `if($this).attr("value")==""){`

How can I determine whether the field is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$(this).val()` instead.  That's jQuery's way of getting field values.

```
if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next("div").toggleClass("selected").fadeTo(250, 0.5);
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: ok ill give it a shot, could you please tell me if it looks like I am setting up my if then statement correctly?  if($(this).val()==""){

Comment: it worked! thank you very much!!! And to think that I banged my head against this for over an hour before I came here!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `.step` is an input field, this should do:

```
if (this.value == "")
```

Comment: Ah, forgot about `val()` of course. Fair enough, both methods work fine (but if you're in a jQuery context anyway, `val()` is preferable for consistency)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) that can be used to get the value of a form element. You could compare this to the empty string:

```
if($(this).val() !== "") {
    // It has been filled
} else {
    // It is empty
}
```

Comment: thank you very much too, very clear way of writing it for a beginner like myself.